# Car won’t start without a jump, and then shuts off when I touch the brake

Tags: battery, stall, suzuki

2010 Sukuki won’t start unless I jump it, and when I put my foot on the brake it shuts off and will not start again.
Turn signals and lights come on and the door buzzer buzzes.

Comment: That sounds like your battery can source just enough power to run the fuel pump, computer, and injectors, but the added draw from the tail lights lowers the voltage too much and the car shuts off. I'd guess that your alternator isn't working to generate power, or that your battery is bad and is drawing down the system voltage. I'd recommend testing the output voltage of the alternator and testing the battery to see if it has low voltage or is unable to source much current.

Comment: @the_storyteller you should add this as an answer. Sounds right to me.

Comment: @kyle_engineer, I would if I knew it was a solution, but it's more of an educated guess, not a categorically correct answer. Thanks for the confirmation though.

Comment: @the_storyteller sure. I'd say it's right in that it is *at a minimum* the correct place to start diagnostics. Maybe it opens a larger can of worms, maybe you're correct at step 1. Anyway, just my 2c as a fellow user. ;)